# polkadot.js: Unable to create Enum

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

`types.json`:

```
{
  "WorkerId": {
    "_enum": {
      "Single": "Single",
      "Double": "Double"
    }
  },
  "Single": "u8",
  "Double": "(u8, u8)",
}
```

substrate code:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn worker_infos)]
pub type WorkerInfos<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, WorkerId, WorkerInfo, ValueQuery>;


pub enum WorkerId {
    Single(u8),
    Double(u8, u8),
}
```

I want to query `worker_infos` by `WorkerId` in polkadot.js:

```js
    workerIds = [1,2]
    api.query[wrpc][wcallable]
      .multi(workerIds, (results) => {
        ...
      })
      .then((unsub) => {
        ...
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

Error info:

```
REGISTRY: Error: Unable to create Enum via index 2, in Single, Double
```

Any ideas on this? **How to pass workerIds(enum type) in polkadot.js?**

Comment: Did you try passing the raw type directly into the enum declaration? Might just be a limitation or bug in the Polkadot JS types generator, but would be good to know if using the types directly works.

Answer (score 1):

{ Single: 1 } or { Double: [2, 3] }